# where and how to use Page.RegisterRequiresViewStateEncryption()?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I would like to know how to register a control with viewState encryption.
The syntax of `Page.RegisterRequiresViewStateEncryption()` method does not indicate particular control other than the page object. Provide a sample code to answer this question would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[RegisterRequiresViewStateEncryption()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerrequiresviewstateencryption.aspx) is to be used with the [ViewStateEncryptionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.viewstateencryptionmode.aspx) property of the `Page` object. That property supports three values:

- `Always`: The page's view state will *always* be encrypted.
- `Never`: The page's view state will *never* be encrypted, even if `RegisterRequiresViewStateEncryption()` is called by a control or the page itself.
- `Auto`: The page's view state will be encrypted *only if* `RegisterRequiresViewStateEncryption()` is called by a control or the page itself.

So, if you call `Page.RegisterRequiresViewStateEncryption()` from, say, one of your control's `OnLoad()` method, or from the `OnLoad()` method or `Page_Load` event of your page, the view state will be encrypted, unless your page's `ViewStateEncryptionMode` property is set to `Never`.

The first link above contains a code sample that enables view state encryption on postback if the end user chose to retrieve sensitive information.